# Classes folder not appearing in Groups & Files Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

The code files have suddenly disappeared from the left tree pane on my Xcode. I tried to drag and drop the classes folder from the file system but this starts giving syntax errors.
Please help.

Comment: Source files can't disappear without a reason. What were you doing before they disappeared?

Comment: I guess I have deleted them! Is there any way to get them back .. The project works but I find it difficult to navigate between source files

Comment: Right click on your project and select Add->Existing Files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project builds then you haven't deleted them, you've probably dragged them into another group[ by mistake :)

Open all the other groups and you might see the Classes folder as a subfolder. Just drag it back out again.

---

NB Go to Build->'Clean all Targets' and then build it again. If it builds without errors then my answer is probably right. If it doesn't build then I'm absolutely wrong :)